# How to append more data in FormData for django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

My reference is here [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

The answer on that link worked on my program. My problem is how to append more data in FormData? I'm using python django and I would like to know where I can put the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and `inputfilename`

Before, this is what I have in form data

```
var form_data = {
    inputfilename: $("#filename").val(),
    inputfile: $("#file").val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    ajax: 1
};
```

and now,

```
var form_data = new FormData();    
form_data.append('file', input.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what's the issue you are having. Just append the csrf token the way you append the file:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append('file', input.files[0] );
fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf_token);
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: callback
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the csrf token correctly? Is the request accepted, if you add `@csrf_exempt` to the Django view?

Comment: I changed this `input.files[0]` to `$('input[type="file"]')[0].files` and `csrf_token` to `$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()` and so it works.